# Equal height of some thumbnails

Tags: css, html, height, multiple-columns

I'm working on a project and I got stuck on something, easy to say but I can't fix it :)
So, I am using bootstrap grid system, and in a content, I want to put thumbnails (just a photo and some text below) six per row, fine until now, the text below the image differs from thumbnail to thumbnail, but I want every thumbnail to take the height of the heighest , wich will be auto, and the text to be vertically aligned on that div :)
Can someone help?

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" >
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                    <i class="icon-book"></i>
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Facultati</h3>
                </div>                  
                <div id="main-panel" class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row gallery">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <a href="faculty-page.html">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img style="height:100px" src="img/faculty.jpg" alt="Cloud Admin" class="img-responsive">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h3 style="text-align:center;font-size:20px">Facultatea de Matematica si Informatica</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <a href="faculty-page.html">
                                <div class="thumbnail" >
                                    <img style="height:100px" src="img/faculty.jpg" alt="Examene" class="img-responsive">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h3 style="text-align:center">Examene</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <a href="faculty-page.html">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img style="height:100px" src="img/faculty.jpg" alt="Cloud Admin" class="img-responsive">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h3 style="text-align:center">Lab1.doc</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <a href="faculty-page.html">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img style="height:100px" src="img/faculty.jpg" alt="Cloud Admin" class="img-responsive">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h3 style="text-align:center">Facultatea de Geografie</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the HTML

```
.caption{
display:table;
height:auto;}


.caption h3{
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center; 
 }
```

and here the CSS (just for this part) 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to implement this with CSS only (and it might take quite a lot of "hacking"). Instead you could use a javascript approach by calculating the maximum height of those thumbnails and then applying the max-value to all of them.

here is a function I've made few months ago (it's in jquery but you could easily rewrite it into "vanilla" javascript).

```
function maxHeight(selected){
    var current = 0, max = 0;

    $(selected).each(function(){
        current = $(this).height();
        max = Math.max(current, max);
    });
    $(selected).height(max);
}

maxHeight("thumbnail");
```

Comment: Nice! Bootstrap requires jQuery.

Comment: @cab the answers should be as broad as possible, if I answer this only for projects that require `bootstrap` and `jquery` then the other people that have the same question but with different requirements will need to write a question of their own (with the same context)

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna implement it and see if it works :)